# Where are the internal error pages defined

Tags: scala, playframework

Where can I find the implementation of methods like `Ok`, `BadRequest`, `InternalServerError`, `NotFound`?

I looked at play documentation but couldn't find it. Specifically, I looked at `Results.class` but the implementation there seem different than expected. For eg, the `Ok` method we use in code takes an argument as follows:

```
Ok(views.html.index("Welcome")(userForm))
```

but the implementation of `Ok` in `Results.class` is a

```
val Ok : Results.this.Status = { /* compiled code */ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scala (on the example of Play 2.5.x, the idea is similar in other versions as well):

The source of the `Ok` (`BadRequest` is very similar): https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L497

```
/** Generates a ‘200 OK’ result. */
val Ok = new Status(OK)
```

So, `Ok` is the object, and `Ok("some string")` is the object in function notation. In the objects notation it is `Ok.apply("some string")`

The source of the `Status` code: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L362-L379

`apply` code for `Status` is

```
/**
 * Set the result's content.
 *
 * @param content The content to send.
 */
def apply[C](content: C)(implicit writeable: Writeable[C]): Result = {
  Result(
    header,
    writeable.toEntity(content)
  )
}
```

Then you can go to `Writeable` class: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/Writeable.scala

There are many `writables` for different types, for example for `String` it is

```
implicit def wString(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[String] = Writeable[String](str => codec.encode(str))
```

`Codec` implementation you can find here:  https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L278-L306